# Add a HTML comment using Eclipse RAP

Tags: comments, eclipse-rap

How do I add a HTML comment using [Eclipse RAP](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/) 3.9 E4?

The following adds the comment text to the HTML albeit in a `<div>`.  I would like the comment text in a `<!-- -->`.

```
public class MainEntry extends AbstractEntryPoint
{
   protected void createContents(Composite parent)
   {
      Label comment;

      comment = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);

      comment.setText("This is my comment");
      comment.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You should not need to interact with the generated html in a such direct way... Perhaps a browser-widget (which turns into an iframe on the client side) is the right thing for you?

Comment: @mifritscher It's been a year and I forgot the actual need.  A browser widget would be worse since the solution in the question only creates a `<div>`.